Push-to-lock & a button pressing mechanism to release
I need a secure attachment mechanism for a robot arm tool changer that can snap one part into place by pushing it in and release it by pressing a button. This mechanism must reliably handle around 25 kg without any backlash, ensuring the part doesn't detach if the robot arm collides with an object or is accidentally bumped. It must be durable enough to withstand such impacts. I will turn this into a company in the future, so it needs to feel premium.
I am familiar with push-push latches, but they aren't suitable due to their vulnerability to accidental disengagement. My preference is for a mechanical solution without electronic components to maintain simplicity and reliability. Additionally, I want the mechanism to produce a distinct click sound when the part is securely locked in place, providing audible confirmation to the user.
For the design, I need to connect two cylinders, each 59 mm in diameter and approximately 8 mm in height. The connection might benefit from a joint that aids in proper alignment. Here is a basic visual:

Example:
I found a great example of what I need to make here. At about 1:10 in the video, you can see the button to release it.
Some ideas:
I am thinking I could have a ball detent mechanism using this solenoid valve where the spring-loaded ball is housed in one part (green) and the corresponding indent is on the other part (red). I'm thinking of using two sets of these for enhanced security and to prevent accidental releases using two release buttons. However, I'm unsure how to design the button to effectively retract the spring.
While an electronically activated solenoid valve could serve this purpose, I am hesitant due to its added weight, cost, size, and complexity. An alternative might be a buckle mechanism, but my initial attempts with 3D-printed models proved insufficiently durable due to the necessary thin material. It was also difficult to achieve zero backlash.
I found this component from McMaster-Carr that could be of use, but it does not detail the internal mechanism.
Question:
Could you recommend an existing design or provide guidance on how to develop such a mechanism? An illustrative image would be highly beneficial.
Possible solution from @user721108:
User721108 suggested in the comments that a camera mount could be a viable option. I found this camera mount on Amazon, which appears to be a promising solution. The product listing does not provide a detailed view of the mechanism, so I will purchase it to disassemble and examine how it works. This seems like a great solution.

What is roughly diameter, thickness of those discs and how strongly locked has it to be? This reminds of quick release plates for camera/tripod, those come with various locking mechanisms, buttons or levers or screws and could be a path to follow

the discs are 59mm in diameter, about 8mm in height, and should hold about 25kg.

Is that linear dovetail joint an imposed design constraint? Regarding the purpose, It seems something annular could be a better fit. Like a lens mount for camera. Those have minimum backlash and a fancy unlock button.

No, the dovetail joint was just an idea. It can be removed.

@user721108   I edited my question to include your suggestion. If you post an answer explaining it in more detail I may accept it as the answer. I will wait a couple of days to see if anyone can think of a better solution.

I can't post an answer. I just think studying various existing mounts (even if of unrelated purpose) is a good thing. Maybe identifying the worst case tool that this mount will carry (25kg can pack a lot of torque on lots of axes i guess) could help anyone knowledgeable come up with a useful answer

I bought the camera mount that I linked in my question.  It just arrived, and it thankfully has no backlash, is easy to use, and will work perfectly for my robot arm. user721108 , I'm not sure why you said you cannot post an answer, but if you do, I will accept it.

Please consider to edit your question by adding details of the interaction between these parts. A sketch or diagram or photo would be very helpful. For example, two pieces of tubing sized to allow one to telescope into the other can be secured with a spring loaded pin. These are used in pop-up display tents to position the leg extensions. I have a battery powered shower scrubber which uses the same mechanics to allow longer or shorter rods to be added or removed by the push of a button.
From the EZTube web site a 20 second video on YouTube shows an example of these push to release mechanisms being used on square tubing. If cylindrical tubing is used, one should have a means of aligning and/or preventing rotation detrimental to the assembly.
If this is not applicable to your assembly, please note the opening paragraph.

I added an image to better explain what I need. The design you sent me seems good, I just need to figure out how to implement it

This image is very helpful and I'll have to ponder the push button option. It might not be the best solution.
